# Как подключить данную библиотеку в проект Андроид?

Tags: java, android, github, android-library

Не понимаю, как подключить [данную](https://github.com/kshoji/javax.sound.midi-for-Android) библиотеку в свой проект и куда прописывать [эти](https://github.com/kshoji/javax.sound.midi-for-Android/wiki/Use-library-with-Android-Studio) зависимости. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Т.к. библиотека находится на Github в публичном репозитории, то есть простой способ её подключить:

в рутовый build.gradle проекта:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

в build.gradle приложения:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.kshoji:javax.sound.midi-for-Android:v0.0.3'
}
```

Подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](https://jitpack.io/#kshoji/javax.sound.midi-for-Android)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 3):

Там кривые ссылки, получилось собрать так:

В `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'jp.kshoji:ble-midi:0.0.9:@aar'
    compile 'jp.kshoji:midi-driver:0.1.4:@aar'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://github.com/kshoji/BLE-MIDI-for-Android/raw/master/library/repository' }
    maven { url 'https://github.com/kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver/raw/master/MIDIDriver/snapshots' }
}
```

Comment: Там в файле Gradle есть два поля репозитория. В какой из них добавлять правильно?)
buildscript or allproject?

Comment: Попробовал во всякому, но в проекте даже не получается получить объект класса Synthesizer... Студия его красным обводит без каких-либо вариантов :(

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему вы используете Android Studio и gradle.

Зависимости прописаны в build.gradle файле проекта.
Их можно установить вручную, поправив файл, или с помощью интерфейса студии.

Найдите файл

```
+ проект
  + приложение 
    + src
    + build.gradle приложения  <-- этот файл
  + build.gradle проекта
```

добавьте в него зависимости, как указано.

С помощью студии:
`Правой кнопкой на приложении` - `Open module settings` - `Dependencies`