# Не получается добавить библиотеку с GitHub в андроид-проект

Tags: android, github, android-library

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить [данную](https://github.com/KyoSherlock/MidiDriver) библиотеку с гитхаба в свой андроид-проект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот аналогичный вопрос: [Подключение сторонней библиотеки в проект Android Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425567/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-android-studio)

Если разработчик не предоставил дополнительной информации или .jar файла — склоньте проект с гита и подключите его как модуль (по ссылке есть подробное описание с картинками, переписывать его сюда нет необходимости).

Comment: Для библиотек, выложенных на гитхабе есть более простое решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735008/735072#735072